# Web Scraping in python without "ids" in table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi this is my first time attempting to webscrape in python using Beautiful soup. The problem that i am having is I am trying to scrape data off of a table from a website but the tables do not have ids. Say I was able to get the id of the element above the tr in the table is there anyway to scrape the data under that element.

This is what I am trying to scrape
[image]

I am able to grab the id="boat" in the first tr but I am trying to access the tr underneath it the problem is it has a class of "bottomline" this is a problem because the class name "bottomline" is used in multiple tr's which all have different values and i cant access the div with the class name of "tooltip" because the name is also used in multiple divs

So ultimitly my question is, is there away to scrape the data in tr that is under id="boat"

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: Please provide the URL

Comment: "https://www.minecraftcraftingguide.net"

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful Soup builds a tree for you.  You are not required to have any identifying information about an element in order to find it, as long as you know the structure of the tree... which you do.

In your example, you already have the `<strong>` element with the ID you were looking for.  If you look at the HTML, you see it is a child of a `<td>`, which is itself a child of a `<tr>`.  BS4 allows you to move up the tree by iterating `parents` of an element:

```
name = soup.find(id = 'boat') 
print(name)

for parent_row in name.parents:
    if parent_row.name == 'tr': 
        break
```

At this point the variable `parent_row` will be set to the `<tr>` containing your `<strong>`.

Next, you can see that the data you are looking for is in the next `<tr>` after `parent`, which in BS4 terminology is a `sibling` of `parent_row`.  You can iterate `siblings` similarly:

```
for sibling_row in parent_row.next_siblings:
    if sibling_row.name == 'tr': 
        break
```

And at this point you have the row you need, and you can get the content:

```
content = list(sibling_row.stripped_strings)
print(content)
```

Putting it all together using the code in your later post:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.minecraftcraftingguide.net"
r = requests.get(URL)
   
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
print(soup.prettify())

name = soup.find(id = 'boat') 
print(name)

for parent_row in name.parents:
    if parent_row.name == 'tr': 
        break

for sibling_row in parent_row.next_siblings:
    if sibling_row.name == 'tr': 
        break

content = list(sibling_row.stripped_strings)
print(content)
```

Comment: thanks ill test that ASAP and let you know what happens

Answer (score 0):

If you are scraping from a table, maybe `pd.read_html()` from the Pandas module can help here. I cannot reproduce your example because you have not offered any reproducible code, but you could try the following:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
# Make a request and try to get the table using pandas
r = requests.get("your_url")
df = pd.read_html(r.content)[0]
```

If pandas is able to capture a dataframe from the response then you should be able to access all the data in the table as if you were using pandas over a normal dataframe. This has worked for me many times when performing this kind of tasks.

Comment: so how would i use it in my application, like how do i read the tr value underneath the one i am in. Sorry i am a bit confussed.

Answer (score 0):

this is what my code looks like

````
from ask_sdk_core.dispatch_components import AbstractRequestHandler, AbstractExceptionHandler
from ask_sdk_core.handler_input import HandlerInput
from ask_sdk_model.ui import SimpleCard
import feedparserimport requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser                                                             

URL = "https://www.minecraftcraftingguide.net"
r = requests.get(URL)
   
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
print(soup.prettify())

name = soup.find(id = 'boat') 
print(name)

class MinecraftHelperIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
  """Handler for minecraft helper intent"""
  def can_handle(self, handler_input):
    return ask_utils.is_intent_name("MinecraftHelperIntent")(handler_input)

    

  def handle(self, handler_input):
    slots = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots
    # interactionModel.languageModel.intents[].slots[].multipleValues.enabled
    item = slots['Item'].value
    itemStr = item.str();
    

    imgStart = 'https://www.minecraftcraftingguide.net/img/crafting/'
    imgMid = item
    imgEnd = '-crafting.png'
    imgLink = imgStart + imgMid + imgEnd
    print(imgLink)

    speak_output = f'To craft that you will need {item} here is a link {imgLink}'

    return (
      handler_input.response_builder
          .speak(speak_output)
          .set_card(SimpleCard('test', 'card_text'))#might need to link account for it to work
          .response
    )```
````

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue recently... but I'm using selenium instead of Beautiful soup. In my case to fix the issue I have to:

- first identify a table parameter to use as reference, then
- follow the table tree on the on web page that I was trying to scrape, after that
- put everything in a xpath element like the code before:

```
    from pyotp import *
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    get_the_value_from_td = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@width="517"]/tbody/tr[8]/td[8]').text
```

This link was very helpful to me: https://www.guru99.com/selenium-webtable.html